# C++ Iterator generalize - different containers, same type

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I know there is no abstract base class for iterators in C++ but I have a specific question I can't find an answer to. In the documentation for [list::begin()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/begin/) this example of iterating over list is given:

```
std::cout << "mylist contains:";
for (std::list<int>::iterator it=mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it)
  std::cout << ' ' << *it;
...
```

And for [list::rbegin()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/rbegin/) this is given:

```
std::cout << "mylist backwards:";
for (std::list<int>::reverse_iterator rit=mylist.rbegin(); rit!=mylist.rend(); ++rit)
  std::cout << ' ' << *rit;
...
```

Do I really have to specify that the iterator is a *list* iterator -  `std::list<int>::iterator`? This means I can't generalize between iterators over the same type (say `int`) from different containers?! And further, do I really have to distinguish between a std::list::iterator and std::list::reverse_iterator? According to the documentation they are both [ForwardIterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/)?

How can I avoid these qualifications? It seems against the whole point of having iterators.

Comment: Use templates.. that's the whole point of having templates :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb What? I am using templates.

Comment: Deduce the iterator type from the template parameters, or use a similar model with ForwardIterator etc. that the standard library does. I can provide an example if you show some more code

Comment: @MattMcNabb Hmm OK so template the iterator type. Are you suggesting I do something like this: `template <class T, class U> void iterate_it(T<U>::iterator it);`. I can't get that to compile.

Comment: You'd need to show the function this is in (i.e. where `mylist` comes from)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Well, I have not written the function, I was just thinking in general how would I provide a arbitrary "ForwardIterator" to an arbitrary function. I still have not got over this hurdle. This iterator stuff seems truly bonkers. I will get there :).

Comment: You'd make the function take `template<typename ForwardIterator>`. This has the slight drawback that the function's implementation will have to be in its header.   To improve on that, you could make the header have a generic algorithm that uses the forward iterator and calls some other function for each argument .

Comment: Ah I got it: `template <class T> void iterate_it(std::iterator<T, std::forward_iterator_tag> it);`. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You tagged C++11, so to avoid those declarations, you can use a range `for-loop` to iterate between `begin()` and `end()`:

```
std::cout << "mylist contains:";
for (auto item : mylist)
  std::cout << item << *it;
```

And yes, you would need to differentiate the case for reverse iterators, since they really are another type of iterators (going reverse on the `std::list`, which is a doubly linked list, so the output of your loop will indeed be different).

**EDIT:**

The STL way of avoiding writing handcrafted loops for different containers or iterators types, is to use generic algorithms taking a pair of iterators as their arguments:

```
std::for_each (mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), myfunction);
```

So you can reuse your algorithms with any kind of containers or iterators, without rewriting code. Such algorithms are templates, templated with the iterator types, allowing to provide specialization in some cases (e.g. its easier to do std::sort with random iterators than with forward iterators).

Comment: quantdev; reverse has different implementation obviously but the interface is the same. Also the "auto" is compile time. What about say, providing the iterator from say vector.begin(), and list.begin() to a function in a generic way?

Comment: @FrancisM.Bacon: Make the function a template.

Comment: @FrancisM.Bacon Your function should take an iterator type as a template argument then. Take a look at any of the algorithms in the standard library

Comment: Use templates for that, all the information is available at compile time (this is what `auto` does under the covers, too)

Comment: @FrancisMBacon : see my edit about template algorithms and the STL, hope this helps.

Comment: @quantdev I knew about all those loop constructs but did not know how they worked, which what I was trying to get at.

Comment: Do you want to know how the compiler works with those loops ? Maybe you should edit your question to make it clearer ? Ill be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `auto`, then you don't have to mention the type of container

```
for (auto it=mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it)
  std::cout << ' ' << *it;
```

and

```
for (auto rit=mylist.rbegin(); rit!=mylist.rend(); ++rit)
  std::cout << ' ' << *rit;
```

---

Or use `decltype`

```
for (decltype(mylist)::iterator it=mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it)
  std::cout << ' ' << *it;
```

and

```
for (decltype(mylist)::reverse_iterator rit=mylist.rbegin(); rit!=mylist.rend(); ++rit)
  std::cout << ' ' << *rit;
```

---

Or use a range-based `for`

```
for(auto const& elem : mylist) 
  std::cout << ' ' << elem;
```

And if you use Boost you can extend [this functionality](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/reversed.html) to the reverse iterator too

```
for(auto const& elem : (mylist | boost::adaptors::reversed)) {
  std::cout << ' ' << elem;
```

Comment: I left you the `decltype` you could have left me the range loop ;) - nice answer now +1.

Comment: @quantdev Ha! I was still editing when you posted, didn't see your answer till I was done :P

Comment: For the classic for loop, why wouldn't you just use `auto` in that case also? Is there some advantage in using `decltype` there? Or do you just prefer it?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley No, just didn't think of it :)

Comment: Ok I see I can use for(:) or for_each(), but I don't know how to do what they are doing. Looking at the docs for std::sort() for example it says the protocol is `void sort (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);` but as far as I can tell RandomAccessIterator is not a class!?

Comment: @FrancisM.Bacon you are probably reading the wrong documentation. Try [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and follow the link for the **concept** RandomAccessIterator...